How to remove decimal from JavaScript function return
I was hoping someone could guide me maybe it can't be done? I have a function and I'm trying to remove the decimal (I want a whole number return)
function studentsPerAdmin(students, teachers, helpers) {
  const average = students / (teachers + helpers);
  if (average > 10) {
    console.log(`There are on average ${average} students for each educator.`);
  } else {
    console.log('Unfortunately this class will be cancelled due to not having enough students enrolled.');
  }
  return average
}


studentsPerAdmin(41, 1, 2)

I've tried using the math functions such as math.round() but I'm still learning and I don't think I'm using it correctly. So far the result is
There are on average 13.666666666666666 students for each educator.


Welcome to SO! Where and how did you try to use Math.round? Your code doesn't show it.

Please show us how you are using math.round so we can tell you where you've gone wrong

return Math.round(average); should have worked. Notice that it must be uppercase M -- JavaScript is case-sensitive.

@Barmar https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions : "Focus on the explanation rather than providing full source code."
